# rc.local command have user prompt and not run at startup

Tags: command-line, scripts, startup, execute-command

in ubuntu at startup i want to run command just ask user to enter a number.

this command should run recursive in while loop. after user enter a number

a php program process it and again ask user for enter an another number.
i have this script runs perfectly.

then put this script in rc.local file to run at startup. when i manually run "exec rc.local" command it works fine.

but when i restart my system to execute command at startup nothing happen.

i expected after startup a terminal window open and ask for number input, Just like what occurs after running the file manually.

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

set -x                         # tell sh to display commands before execution

while true; do php /var/www/html/eventica/artisan SendRfid:send; sleep 0; done

exit 0
```

Comment: Replace `php` by `/usr/bin/php`.

Comment: as i said script works good when i call it with exec command.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to test it. But I assume that you can create a .sh file and run it on boot via `crontab`.

```
set -x                         # tell sh to display commands before execution

while true; do php /var/www/html/eventica/artisan SendRfid:send; sleep 0; done

exit 0
```

Make a .sh file and save it. (For example, /etc/myscript.sh)
Test run it. If you get a Permission Denied error, run `chmod +x /etc/myscript.sh`

If it works, you can use `profile.d` to run the script on logon.

```
ln -s /etc/myscript.sh /etc/profile.d/myscript.sh
```

That creates a symbolic link to `profile.d`.

Comment: didn't worked for me. nothing happen after startup. i expected to automatically open new terminal window after startup and run predefined command, but nothing happen.

Comment: @mohammadrezvani Does it work if you run the .sh script?

Comment: yes it work when run .sh

Comment: @mohammadrezvani I've updated the answer. Try that.